# Differences between scala and java enumerations

Tags: java, scala, enumeration

I read [an answer on SO where someone said that scala enumerations are useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102834/1454048), and you should just use java enumerations instead if you really need too.

Although I have used java enumerations before, I can't say I fully understand them as I don't code in java during my day job.

Can someone explain the differences between scala and java enumerations, and where exactly the shortcomings in scala enums are?

Comment: Scala's Enumeration is not that behind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537148/scala-java-enumerations It's just not as convenient as Scala's case classes/objects.

Answer (score 4):

The main advantage of Scala's Enumeration is the regularity of the syntax.

If you want to add behavior to elements of your enum, just extend its `Val` class.

Odersky likes them for their simplest use case as named int-valued constants. And he just promised on the mailing list, for the first time, that improved support is on the horizon.

But I [recently](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/blob/b76162a3f8214a4557c99d649f0bd04bce533011/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala#L72) [used](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/blob/b76162a3f8214a4557c99d649f0bd04bce533011/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala#L215) them to replace a list of strings, since the set of values is a bit set, nicer than a set of strings for look-up.

Instead of

```
val stuff = List("foo", "bar", "baz")

object stuff extends Enumeration { val foo, bar, baz = Value }
```

or

```
scala> object stuff extends Enumeration { val foo, bar, baz = Value }
defined object stuff

scala> val junk = new Enumeration { val foo, bar, baz = Value }
junk: Enumeration{val foo: this.Value; val bar: this.Value; val baz: this.Value} = 1

scala> stuff.values contains junk.foo
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : junk.Value
 required: stuff.Value
              stuff.values contains junk.foo
                                         ^
```

Behavior:

```
scala> trait Alias { def alias: String }
defined trait Alias

scala> object aliased extends Enumeration {
     | class Aliased extends Val with Alias {
     |   def alias = toString.permutations.drop(1).next }
     | val foo, bar, baz = new Aliased }
defined object aliased

scala> abstract class X { type D <: Enumeration
     | def f(x: D#Value) = x match { case a: Alias => a.alias
     |   case _ => x.toString } }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X { type D = aliased.type }
defined class Y

scala> new Y().f(aliased.bar)
res1: String = bra

scala> new Y().f(stuff.foo)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : stuff.Value
 required: aliased.Value
              new Y().f(stuff.foo)
                              ^

scala> new X { type D = junk.type }.f(junk.foo)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res4: String = foo
```

`ValueSet` is a bit set:

```
scala> stuff.values contains aliased.bar
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : aliased.Aliased
 required: stuff.Value
              stuff.values contains aliased.bar
                                            ^

scala> stuff.foo + aliased.bar
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : aliased.Aliased
 required: stuff.Value
              stuff.foo + aliased.bar
                                  ^

scala> stuff.foo + stuff.bar
res8: stuff.ValueSet = stuff.ValueSet(foo, bar)
```

Other stuff that seems to work in today's Scala:

```
scala> def f[E <: Enumeration](e: E)(v: e.Value) = e.ValueSet.empty + v
f: [E <: Enumeration](e: E)(v: e.Value)e.ValueSet

scala> f(stuff)(stuff.foo)
res14: stuff.ValueSet = stuff.ValueSet(foo)

scala> def g[E <: Enumeration](e: E)(a: Any) = a match { case _: e.Value => true case _ => false }
g: [E <: Enumeration](e: E)(a: Any)Boolean

scala> g(stuff)(stuff.foo)
res15: Boolean = true

scala> g(stuff)(junk.foo)    // checking outer pointers
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res16: Boolean = false

scala> g(stuff)(aliased.foo)
res17: Boolean = false
```

It looks like Scala is [not entirely friendly to Java enums](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6613):

```
scala> Thread.State.NEW.ordinal
[snip]
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: 
  Unknown type: <notype>(NEW), <notype> [class scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueConstantType, class scala.reflect.internal.Types$NoType$] TypeRef? false
     while compiling: <console>
        during phase: icode
     library version: version 2.11.2
    compiler version: version 2.11.2
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: Apply(method ordinal)
       tree position: line 8 of <console>
            tree tpe: Int
              symbol: final method ordinal in class Enum
   symbol definition: final def ordinal(): Int (a MethodSymbol)
      symbol package: java.lang
       symbol owners: method ordinal -> class Enum
           call site: constructor $read$$iw$$iw in package $line4
```